# rollapply: fix the starting observation in each sliding window?

Tags: r, zoo, rollapply

Simple zoo object is

```
z <- zoo(11:15, as.Date(31:45))
as.data.frame(z) 
            z
1970-02-01 11
1970-02-02 12
1970-02-03 13
1970-02-04 14
1970-02-05 15
1970-02-06 11
1970-02-07 12
1970-02-08 13
1970-02-09 14
1970-02-10 15
1970-02-11 11
1970-02-12 12
1970-02-13 13
1970-02-14 14
1970-02-15 15
as.data.frame(rollapply(z, width=3, mean, align="right"))
           rollapply(z, width = 3, mean, align = "right")
1970-02-03                                       12.00000
1970-02-04                                       13.00000
1970-02-05                                       14.00000
1970-02-06                                       13.33333
1970-02-07                                       12.66667
1970-02-08                                       12.00000
1970-02-09                                       13.00000
1970-02-10                                       14.00000
1970-02-11                                       13.33333
1970-02-12                                       12.66667
1970-02-13                                       12.00000
1970-02-14                                       13.00000
1970-02-15                                       14.00000
```

Is it possible to make that start observation is fixed, i.e. at date "1970-02-04" we have average over '11, 12, 13, 14' not over '12, 13, 14' and so on? Of course one can do it through loop, but if problem is a bit more complicated loops are very slow, and I was looking for something which is as fast as `apply`, or `rollapply`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the width equal to the length of the series and use `partial = TRUE`:

```
rollapplyr(z, length(z), mean, partial = TRUE)
```

You could also use `cumsum(z) / seq_along(z)`

Comment: First one is better, because i need to estimate regressions with left end fixed, so first option is exactly what is needed. It is flexible enough.